# Finding subsequential limits for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find all subsequential limits for the sequence $\{a_n = r^n\sin n\pi x \mid n 
\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $x$ is irrational and $r > 1$.

I know that $r^n$ tends to infinity when $n \rightarrow +\infty$, and $\sin n\pi x$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ (but never equal to $0$). So I am not sure whether $r^n$ will become dominant for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Of course it will become dominant. $\pi$ is known to have finite [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure), hence there are only finitely many numbers such that $|\sin\pi nx|<{1\over n^{10}}$, and $r^n$ grows way faster than $n^{10}$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks. Could you please explain how to derive this from the irrationality measure of $\pi$? By definition we only know $\mid \pi - \frac{p}{q} \mid < \frac{1}{q^{10}}$ has finitely many solutions.

Comment: I just realized I overlooked that $x$, so my reasoning falls apart. It would apply if we had just $\sin n$, because for $|\sin n|$ to be small, we need such $n$ which are close to integer multiples of $\pi$, so that $|\pi-{n\over q}|$ is small. This is not the case, though. We depend on the irrationality measure of $\pi x$, which can be anything. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Think about convergent subsequence.

It's limit must be finite.This give us that $\sin(n\pi x)$ must converge to 0. So non of irrational $x$ gives convergent series.
It is clear that if $x$ is irrational, then $\sin(n\pi x)$ does not converge.
Since $\sin(n\pi x)$ does not converge to 0, the candidates of the limits are only $\infty$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Doesn't $\sin(n \pi x)$ have a subsequence convergent to $0$?

Comment: @JerryIHuang: This is wrong. Since $x$ is irrational, $\{\sin n\pi x:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ and therefore has subsequences converging to every real number in $[-1,1]$. In particular, it has subsequences converging to $0$. The question is whether any of them converge to $0$ fast enough to overcome $r^n$.